# Is javaHashmap completely indexed?

Tags: java, caching, indexing, hashmap

We are using javaHashmap to cache database tables in all our TIBCO applications. I would like to know if JavaHashmap is really indexed or is there a better way to cache database tables in Java (new frameworks can't be added)

```
public class WrapConvTableInfo {

    private static HashMap<String, WrapConvTableInfo_Entry> _wrapConvMap;


public WrapConvTableInfo() {

    _wrapConvMap = new HashMap<String, WrapConvTableInfo_Entry>();
}
```

Above is the code snippet for reference.

Comment: Yes it is indexed; [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "really indexed"? Your example indexes the `WrapConvTableInfo_Entry` objects by a `String` key.

Comment: I am not a Java expert, so you are saying that Hashmap is indexed by String key indexed by default?? We will caching thousands of records

Comment: @AbdulKader If the key is a String (as in your `HashMap<String, WrapConvTableInfo_Entry>` example), then yes, it is indexed by a String key.

Comment: @Eran any better way to doing it??

Comment: @AbdulKader That depends on the requirements. If there is a single `String` property by which you need to search for `WrapConvTableInfo_Entry` instances, your `HashMap<String, WrapConvTableInfo_Entry>` is a good solution.

Comment: Why don't you use Redis cache instead of using HashMap? HashMap shouldn't be use for caching. It will degrade your application performance as and when size is increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` is a key-value store and not a table. There is no concept of indexing here as in the case of tables in the database; it works based on hashing the keys.

Each `HashMap` contains something called buckets. The keys are hashed, and the hashed values are divided by the number of buckets. The remainder is the bucket number in which your value goes.

For example, say my HashMap has 16 buckets.

Now if I assume I am inserting a key value pair `<foo,bar>` into my `HashMap`.

- First the hash of `foo` is computed. For the purpose of this example, let’s say the hash returned is 61.
- Now 61 % 16 (remainder) is 1. So your value goes into bucket one.
- Thus all the values that are being inserted are being divided into buckets like this. If your hashing function is good then all the buckets should more or less have equal values.

Fetching values from HashMap

- First the hash of `foo` and the bucket number is computed similar to insertion.
- Now your value has to be searched in the key,value pairs present only in the bucket. So this saves time. In Java 8, if a bucket has more than eight values, the bucket stores values in the form of a tree for faster access.

If you are using `HashMap` for caching you need to be spend some time on things like how big should it initially be? When should your `HashMap` grow (`loadFactor`) and number of buckets it should have small number of buckets will result in too many values to search from. On the other hand, too many buckets lead to wastage of L1 cache on the CPU. Moreover, **if your application is multi-threaded HashMap is not thread-safe, and you will end up with a corrupted cache**. You need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in that case.